# cannot add angular directive to element dynamically

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add ng-srcset to an image in link function.
When i pass a constant string like "./temp/img3.jpg" it work correctly
and add ng-srcset to my image.

```
link :function(scope,element){
    element.attr("ng-srcset","./temp/img3.jpg");
    $compile(element)(scope);
}
```

but when i try to pass a variable(checked and has a valid value) as attr value,ng-srcset not added to img.

```
link :function(scope,element){
    //scope.imageSource => ./temp/img3.jpg
    element.attr("ng-srcset",scope.imageSource);
    $compile(element)(scope);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to add `ng-srcset` via a directive? Also, you can't invoke `$compile` on the same element (i.e. it's infinite recursion) the directive is applied to. Something else you haven't mentioned is likely causing you a problem because it's straight-forward enough to attach `ng-srcset` via a directive — http://plnkr.co/edit/tMzfht01oLXaz0U3pLdf?p=preview

Comment: thank you for replying.
you are right.
can i use  interpolated string as attribute value?(imageSource contain interpolated string)

Comment: Absolutely, even the [documentation on `ng-srcset`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrcset) suggests it. Example of it in use: http://plnkr.co/edit/LGqE9FWZFePoCZIxC3hd?p=preview

Comment: should i delete this question?

Comment: Glad I helped. I can add my comments as an answer if you want to accept it, otherwise feel free to remove.

Comment: if u think its helpful add as answer.ill accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment trail, there's no need to apply the `ng-srcset` attribute via a directive when you can assign it directly with an interpolated variable value.

The [documentation for `ng-srcset`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrcset) also contains an example which prescribes the use of interpolation.